# Windows service threading with looping and WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, windows-services

First off, I will be talking about some legacy code and we are trying to avoid changing it as much as possible.  Also, my experience with windows services and WCF is a bit limited so some of the questions may be a bit newbie.  Just to give a bit of context before the question.

We have an existing service that loops.  It checks via a database call to see if it has records to process.  If it does not find any records, it sleeps for 30 seconds and then wakes back up to try again.

I would like to add an entry point to this service that would allow me to pass a record to this service in addition to it processing the records from the database.  So the basic flow would be.

Loop
* Read record from database
* If no record from DB, process any records that were passed in via the entry point.
* No records at all, sleep for 30 seconds.

My concern is this.  Is it possible to implement this in one service such that I have the looping process but I also allow for calls to come in at any time and add additional items to a queue that can be processed within the loop.  My concern is with concurrency and keeping the loop and the listener from stepping on each other.

I know this question may not be worded quite right but I am on the new side with working with this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of 'entry point' - what is it that will signal this entry point, and how will it do it?  If it is important that the legacy code is changed as little as possible, can you not just add this 'event' data to the database table?   Just off-hand, 'event' data could easily be sent to the service via TCP/pipes and queued off to the processing thread which, normally, waits on the queue with a 30-sec timeout.  If it was me, I would be itching to add a stored procedure/trigger that would queue up an entry to tell the service immediately that a record is available, but I guess that's out :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My concern is with concurrency and keeping the loop and the listener from stepping on each other.

This shouldn't be an issue, provided you synchronize access correctly.

The simplest option might be to use a thread safe collection, such as a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), to hold your items to process. The WCF service can just add items to the collection without worry, and your next processing step would handle it.  The synchronization in this case is really minimal, as the queue would already be fully thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am going to try some stress testing this evening with your suggestion but it sounds like what I need.  To be honest, that was the main issue I was worried about (how to manage the queue thread safe).

Comment: @Bomlin You might want to look at BlockingCollection as well - using it with GetConsumingEnumerable makes things like this easy, and can actually completely eliminate the 30 second sleep, since it'll just process as items are added without having to have the timer...

Comment: Reed, your suggestion with ConcurrentQueue worked great.  I wrote a service that was looping and had the listener.  I then wrote a client that spawned 10 separate threads each adding a large volume of items.  I randomized both the queuing of items and how long it took to process them inside the loop.  From what I can tell, no concurrency issues at all with 10,000 items.

As an additional note to above I should have also mentioned that this process is slated to be replaced in a few months.  That's why I am doing this band-aid type coding.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Reed's excellent answer, you might want to persist the records in a [MSMQ queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx) to prevent your service from losing records on shutdown, restart, or crash of your service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I would love to have used it but for reasons I can't go into here, I was told that MSMQ was not an option.  Business reasons not technical reasons.